# does applet size causes a browser to crash

Tags: browser, applet, crash, size

I will be running my applet on almost all the browsers for nearly minimum of 14hrs will that cause the browser to crash or hang.My applet will basiclly upload a file to remote server via ftp.

My applet size  is about 1.5mb.

Best Regards,
Sagar

Answer (score 1):

There's no reason the Applet or the browser should crash if your Applet doesn't allocate too much memory. Standard Java heap size is 64Mb so its quite comfortable. Moreover, your application seems to be streaming content and should not retain it in the memory. As for the size of the Applet itself, 1.5Mb is totally OK.

That being said, I would recommend going to a webstart application instead of Applets, because, well, I've had too many problems with Applets. Plugins installations, security constraints, etc... I try to avoid this technology whenever possible.

Comment: +1 for the suggestion of [Java Web Start](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/java-web-start/info).